# Openshift 503 on node.js app with hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift, hapi.js

I have a node.js app using hapi that I'm trying to host on OpenShift. I've uploaded the app to the server, it apparently reads the package.json file fine and runs the app.js file.

However, when I visit the site, I receive a 503 error.

Package.json file:

```
{
"name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "after": "^0.8.1",
    "bcryptjs": "2.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "forever": "^0.15.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "handlebars": "4.0.5",
    "hapi": "^8.8.1",
    "hapi-auth-cookie": "^3.1.0",
    "knex": "^0.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.8.0",
    "request": "^2.69.0",
    "tree-model": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

*note: repository information was removed from the package.json paste.

app.js file:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./bin/dbcfg.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        process.env.client = data.client;
        process.env.host = data.connection.host;
        process.env.user = data.connection.user;
        process.env.password = data.connection.password;
        process.env.database = data.connection.database;
        fs.readFile('./bin/strategycfg.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            var strategyCFG = JSON.parse(data);
            server = new Hapi.Server();
            server.connection({ port : 3000, address: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1' });
            server.register(require('hapi-auth-cookie'), function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                server.auth.strategy('default', 'cookie',strategyCFG);
                server.auth.default('default');
                const defaultContext = {
                    title: 'App'
                };
                server.views({
                    engines: {
                        html: require('handlebars')
                    },
                    context: defaultContext,
                    path: ['public/html', 'private/html'],
                    layoutPath: 'public/templates',
                    layout: 'default'
                    //,
                    //helpersPath: 'views/helpers',
                    //partialsPath: 'views/partials'
                });
            });

            server.route(require('./lib/Routes'));

            server.start(function() {
                console.log('Running on 3000');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

});

I ran rhc tail -a appname and received this:

```
==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <==
[WARNING] 090/180806 (276379) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 090/180806 (276379) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 090/180806 (276379) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 090/180806 (276379) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 090/180919 (276379) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 090/180919 (279772) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 090/180919 (279772) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 090/180919 (279772) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 090/180919 (279772) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 090/180923 (279772) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.

==> app-root/logs/haproxy_ctld.log <==
I, [2016-03-30T22:04:51.536078 #521102]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-30T22:11:34.136340 #49489]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-30T22:25:04.802167 #98826]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-30T22:29:56.842182 #117627]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-30T22:32:36.247075 #130978]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-30T22:39:12.046805 #156995]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-30T23:01:39.741187 #237078]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-30T23:07:00.948129 #255019]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-31T18:08:07.635718 #276393]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-31T18:09:20.552771 #279795]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld

==> app-root/logs/npm-debug.log <==
5 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
6 error System Linux 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
7 error command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install"
8 error cwd /var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxx/app-root/logs
9 error node -v v0.10.35
10 error npm -v 1.4.28
11 error path /var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxx/app-root/logs/package.json
12 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
13 error errno 34
14 verbose exit [ 34, true ]

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
DEBUG: Sending SIGTERM to child...
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program 'server.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxx/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxx/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.
Running on 3000
```

The "Running on 3000" makes me think the app is running, but the OpenShift site gives me a 503.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use host instead of address like this:

```
server.connection({ host:'0.0.0.0', port: 3000});
```

Also I think open shift also expose an environment variable for the port.